# codeigniter - retrieve controller variables in view (using $this)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

in my controller i have an public variable i want to use in my view.

```
public $header = array("show_menu"=>true);
```

Traditional i would pass variables as an array to the `load->view("incl_header",$header)` function, however i have noticed that in my view i can retrieve variables of my controller like so:

```
echo  $this->header['show_menu'];
```

Are there any problems retrieving variables like this in my view file?

I am using codeigniter 2.1.3

Comment: In your view do `var_dump($this);` and you will see why you can.

Comment: oke so no problem if i use this method?

Comment: Yes, it is fine, it's just not consistent with what CI users will do. Try to stick with the normal way of accessing the variable using CI just in case such a use will not be possible in future versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do it like that.

If you use var_dump($this) you can see all the variables that are availible in your view.

It's not the normal codeigniter way of retrieving variables in your view.

How ever this might change in futeure releases of codeigniter so you must keep that in mind when using this method.